# Linker can't find lib in Eclipse/JNI/ANT

Tags: c++, eclipse, ant, linker, java-native-interface

I am trying to build a large Java/c++ project involving JNI and ANT in Eclipse, under Linux. One of the source c++ files calls the `log10()` function for mathematical calculations. The project compiles fine, but fails at linking, where it complains that it cannot find the `libm.so` library necessary to link `log10()`.

My problem is that I am unable to properly tell Eclipse to link that file, even after the following steps:

1. Added the correct library path in the linker options,
2. Added a reference to `libm` in the linker include list,
3. Added `-lm` to the full compile options list,
4. Set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to the library's location,
5. Copied the library to the current directory.

What am I doing wrong/has anyone had such experiences with correctly linking libs in Eclipse? Any suggestions?

Comment: Not certain, but are you on an x86_64 machine compiling for 32bit?

Comment: 64 bit, compiling for 64 bit. The linker **explicitly** wants the 64-bit version of `libm.so`, and it even tells me it's location (`/lib64/`). It then proceeds to tell me that I "just" need to link to that location and things will be fine. And when I do, it just spits out the same error.

Comment: And typing `readelf -h /lib64/libm.so.6 | grep Class` gives you `ELF64`? (might not be .so.6, depending on your version)

Comment: Yep, it's an `ELF64`.

Comment: Try moving `-lm` to the end of your linker flags? (Assuming you have more than just that flag)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64855/discussion-between-chrisb2244-and-pickle).

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit confusing.
If you fail to find your library at runtime inside your java environment :

Try loading your .so library inside the java environment before making any calls to log10.

```
System.LoadLibrary("m");
```

Notice how I left "lib" and ".so" out.

However, you are complaining of a Linker problem from C++, you cannot link to a dynamic file. You can only link to a static library, or a static export library (so you need a libm.a file to which to link at compile time, and then your program will require libm.so at runtime).

Could you post the exact message you are receiving and when you are receiving it ?

Comment: The call to `log10()` is done in a c++ file. JNI needs the compiled c++ source files before it can start the Java code, so this is still in the c++ compilation stage. The full error message is as follows: `source.o: undefined reference to symbol 'log10@@GLIBC_2.2.5. ld: note: 'log10@@GLIBC_2.2.5' is defined in DSO /lib64/libm.so.6 so try adding it to the linker command line`

Comment: Then indeed , what chrisb suggested in his comments is the correct approach. You need to link libm statically (add -lm to your complier flags , preferably at the end of include libraries statement)... It's weird thou that this approach didn't solve your problem. Could you please post the compile command you're using  ? Can you compile a Hello World using math.h and -lm ?

Comment: Yes of course hello world and other minimal compiles work. This is a HUGE project consisting of a lot of source files, so I think I need to look through the individual ANT makefiles to make sure -lm is there when it is needed. However, with the steps I have already done and mentioned above, this **should work**.